# Running functions after a drag occurs?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to run a block of code after a drag occurs in my program. I had thought that the following would work:

```
//behavior for a dragged point
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .on("drag", dragmove);

    function dragmove(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")");

        //events to update line to fit dots
        updateXs();
        updateLineData();

        //update line
        d3.select(".myLine").transition()
            .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData));

    }
```

But after seeing it run I think that the block is running while the drag is occurring and the object is moving, which may be causing it to not work correctly. What I want to find is the correct method for handling code that should run after a drag completely occurs. If there's a way to make the line update while the point is being dragged, that would be really cool and preferred, but I don't mind having it execute after the drag finishes, either.

Here's the full code:
https://jsfiddle.net/cuhwvj8t/4/

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#on)? There's a `dragend` event.

Comment: But is there a way to have it update while the drag is still occurring? I was trying to get the line to move with the dot, rather than just jumping to it.

Comment: The line is updating; it looks like you're not updating the data correctly.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Is there any reason why not? I don't see any flaws in the reasoning.

Comment: I've updated it in https://jsfiddle.net/cuhwvj8t/5/, and it seems like the line points are compounding and increasing, despite the 
LineData = []; that occurs first.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what's supposed to happen. I don't know what the new data is supposed to look like.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Well, in the same way that I had originally set up the line graph to change with the slider's movements, right now I'm trying to get the line to change when a drag occurs so that the line will always go through both points, even when they are moved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86718/discussion-between-gamehen-and-lars-kotthoff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute some code once the drag has completed you should use the [dragend](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#on) event. So you'd use:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
             .on("dragend", function(d) { 
                 // Update lines
             });
```

However you should be able to update the lines during the drag using the `drag` event which you're already wired up to:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
             .on("drag", function(d) { 
                 // Update lines
             });
```